# Regex for dollar amount greater than $500

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match dollar amounts greater than $500.  Signals that it's a dollar amount would be a dollar sign or a decimal point with 2 zeros.

I put my try so far plus sample data at the following link.  Any help would be appreciated!

http://regexr.com/38mh3

Comment: Why do you want to use regex for this?

Comment: `parseFloat(dollars.replace('$','')) > 500`

Comment: because I have a gmail search script that I'm leveraging that takes a regex as input and returns search results.

Comment: @anubhava I'm feeling sleepy by now. Aren't you. I mean the time zone is same :)

Comment: @AmitJoki: Yes it is but I work till late hours :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems weird to validate a number greater than with a regular expression, but it would be something like this

```
^\$([5-9]\d{2}|[1-9]\d{3,})\.\d{2}$
```

Uses an or to do the validation of the range.

- `[5-9]\d{2}`  < matches range from 500 to 999
- `[1-9]\d{3,}` < matches 1000 +

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9N7B3/2/

Comment: Shouldn't you be escaping the first `$`?

Comment: This one is close but there are a few issues I'm trying to work around on it.  First, it matches 500.0 but probably shouldn't.  $500 yes and $500.00 yes and 500.00 yes but probably not 500.0.  Also, it seems to match 1000 and probably shouldn't.  $1000 yes and 1000.00 yes but probably not 1000.